# DataGridView. Run Job while entering new row parallel

Tags: powershell, datagridview, start-job

The script included is to check the replication and repair for each Server that I add. The goal I have in mind is for it to automatically check the connection of each computer as I add them as well as check the uptime.

The current issue I'm having is that it will delay to check the uptime before it allows me to input my next computer.

As you can see in my script I'm trying to use a start-job which is not working at all for me as it says the 'ComputerName' is null, but the ComputerName is set in the `Get-Uptime` function.

I may be going about this all wrong. Any help would be great!!

```
function Check-Replication {
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Import the Assemblies
    #----------------------------------------------
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.ServiceProcess, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    $base64Image = "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"
    $imageBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64Image)
    $memStream = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length)
    $memStream.Write($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length);
    $imageGrey = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromStream($memStream, $true)

    $base64Image = "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"
    $imageBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64Image)
    $memStream = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length)
    $memStream.Write($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length);
    $imageGreen = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromStream($memStream, $true)

    $base64Image = "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"
    $imageBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64Image)
    $memStream = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length)
    $memStream.Write($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length);
    $imageRed = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromStream($memStream, $true)

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $labelTypeEachComputerName = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $textbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
    $datagridview1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'
    $buttonRun = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $Online = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn'
    $Uptime = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'
    $Computer = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'
    $Status = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn'
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Function Get-Uptime
    #----------------------------------------------

    #region - Get-Uptime
    $Uptime1 = {
        function Get-Uptime {
            Params ($ComputerName)
            $global:ComputerName = $row.cells[2].Value
            $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($os.LastBootUpTime) {
                $uptime = (Get-Date) - $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
                #Write-Output ("Last boot: " + $os.ConvertToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime) )
                Write-Output ("" + $uptime.Days + "d " + $uptime.Hours + "h " + $uptime.Minutes + "m" )
            } else {
                Write-Warning "Unable to connect to $computername"
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------

    $FormEvent_Load = {
    }

    $textbox1_Validated = {
        if ($textbox1.Text -ne "") {
            $i = $datagridview1.Rows.Add(1)
            $row = $datagridview1.Rows[$i]
            $row.SetValues(@($imageGrey,'',$textbox1.Text,'pending'))
            $textbox1.Text = ''
            $textbox1.Focus()

        if ($row.Cells[2].Value -ne "") {
            if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $row.cells[2].Value -Count 1 -Quiet) {
                $Time = Get-Date

                Start-Job -InitializationScript $Uptime1 -scriptblock {(Get-Uptime -ComputerName $args[0])} -Args $row.cells[2].Value |
                #Start-Job -InitializationScript $Uptime1 -scriptblock {(Get-Uptime)}|
                Wait-Job | Receive-Job
                $row.SetValues(@($imageGrey,($Uptime),$row.Cells[2].Value))
                #Remove-Job -Name CheckSiteUptime
                $Time = Get-date

                $row.Cells[0].Value = $imageGreen
            } else {
                $row.Cells[0].Value = $imageRed}
            }
        }
    }

    $buttonRun_Click = {
        $datagridview1.Rows | ForEach-Object {
            $row = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow]$_
            $CommandResult = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $row.cells[2].Value -ArgumentList $row -ScriptBlock{
                Param($row)
                Import-Module Hyper-V
                if ((Get-VM -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*SR*'} | Get-VMReplication -ErrorAction Stop).Replicationhealth -eq 'critical') {
                    try{
                        Get-VM -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*SR*'} | Resume-VMReplication -ErrorAction Stop
                        if ((Get-VM -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*SR*'} | Get-VMReplication -ErrorAction Stop).Replicationhealth -eq 'critical') {
                            throw [System.Exception] "Replicationhealth critical"
                        }
                    } catch {
                        try{
                            Get-VM -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*SR*'} | Resume-VMReplication -Resynchronize -ErrorAction Stop
                        } catch {
                            return 'FAILED: Resume-VMReplication -Resynchronize'
                            break
                        }
                        return 'Successful: Resume-VMReplication -Resynchronize'
                        break
                    }
                    return 'Successful: Resume-VMReplication'
                } else {
                    return 'Successful: No action replication is NOT critical'
                }
            }
            switch ($CommandResult) {
                "FAILED: Resume-VMReplication -Resynchronize" {
                    $row.Cells | %{$_.Style.BackColor = 'pink'}
                    $Row.Cells[3].Value = $CommandResult
                }
                "Successful: Resume-VMReplication -Resynchronize" {
                    $row.Cells | %{$_.Style.BackColor = 'lightgreen'}
                    $Row.Cells[3].Value = $CommandResult
                }
                "Successful: Resume-VMReplication" {
                    $row.Cells | %{$_.Style.BackColor = 'lightgreen'}
                    $Row.Cells[3].Value = $CommandResult
                }
                "Successful: No action replication is NOT critical" {
                    $row.Cells | %{$_.Style.BackColor = 'lightgreen'}
                    $Row.Cells[3].Value = $CommandResult
                }
            }
        }
        $datagridview1.ReadOnly = $true
    }

    # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load = {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed = {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try {
            $textbox1.remove_Validated($textbox1_Validated)
            $buttonRun.remove_Click($buttonRun_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($FormEvent_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        } catch {
            Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #>
        }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($labelTypeEachComputerName)
    $form1.Controls.Add($textbox1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($datagridview1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonRun)
    $form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
    $form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
    $form1.ClientSize = '625, 600'
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $False
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $False
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form1.Text = 'Replication Check'
    $form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)
    #
    # labelTypeEachComputerName
    #
    $labelTypeEachComputerName.Location = '20, 18'
    $labelTypeEachComputerName.Name = 'labelTypeEachComputerName'
    $labelTypeEachComputerName.Size = '240, 49'
    #$labelTypeEachComputerName.TabIndex = 5
    $labelTypeEachComputerName.Text = 'Type each computer name ending with a <tab>  it will be added to the list.  Click run when alll have been added.'
    $labelTypeEachComputerName.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # textbox1
    #
    $textbox1.CharacterCasing = 'Upper'
    $textbox1.Location = '20, 81'
    $textbox1.Name = 'textbox1'
    $textbox1.Size = '285, 20'
    #$textbox1.TabIndex = 1
    $textbox1.add_Validated($textbox1_Validated)
    #
    # datagridview1
    #
    $datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = $False
    $datagridview1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = $False
    $datagridview1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = $True
    $datagridview1.AllowUserToResizeRows = $False
    $datagridview1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = 'AutoSize'
    [void]$datagridview1.Columns.Add($Online)
    [void]$datagridview1.Columns.Add($Uptime)
    [void]$datagridview1.Columns.Add($Computer)
    [void]$datagridview1.Columns.Add($Status)
    $datagridview1.columns[0].Width = '40'
    $datagridview1.columns[3].Width = '250'
    $datagridview1.Location = '20, 113'
    $datagridview1.Name = 'datagridview1'
    $datagridview1.ReadOnly = $True
    $datagridview1.Size = '583, 470'
    $datagridview1.TabIndex = 3
    $datagridview1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = "True"
    #
    # buttonRun
    #
    $buttonRun.Location = '325, 80'
    $buttonRun.Name = 'buttonRun'
    $buttonRun.Size = '75, 23'
    $buttonRun.TabIndex = 2
    $buttonRun.TabStop = $False
    $buttonRun.Text = 'Run'
    $buttonRun.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonRun.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonRun.add_Click($buttonRun_Click)
    #
    # Online
    #
    $Online.HeaderText = 'Online'
    $Online.Name = 'Online'
    $Online.DataPropertyName = 'Online'
    #
    # Uptime
    #
    $Uptime.HeaderText = 'Uptime'
    $Uptime.Name = 'Uptime'
    $Uptime.ReadOnly = $True
    #
    # Computer
    #
    $Computer.HeaderText = 'Server'
    $Computer.Name = 'Server'
    $Computer.ReadOnly = $True
    #
    # Status
    #
    $Status.HeaderText = 'Status'
    $Status.Name = 'Status'
    $Status.ReadOnly = $True

    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
Check-Replication | Out-Null
```

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Because PowerShell jobs run in a separate runspace, even declaring a variable as $global: does not make it available inside your job. Instead, you need to pass the value in to your job when you create it.

For example, you could change your code as follows:

```
...
Function Get-Uptime {
    params ($ComputerName)
    $global:ComputerName = $ComputerName
... 
Start-Job -InitializationScript $Uptime1 -scriptblock {(Get-Uptime -ComputerName $args[0])} -Args $row.cells[2].Value
```

A similar issue is described here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5b369c15-d2ad-4ee8-a1fc-3f0ca8df230a/powershell-jobs-and-global-variables?forum=ITCG

Another resource on some options other than PS jobs, which tend to be relatively inefficient: https://randombrainworks.com/2018/01/28/powershell-background-jobs-runspace-jobs-thread-jobs/

Comment: I've updated my initial post with your recommendations and I'm having the same issues. Looking through the links you included.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around your base issue of de-coupling your form/GUI from your backend code is to use runspaces and a synchronized hashtable. The advantage of this model is that your can have many threads simultaneously performing work and actively updating your form, and instead of passing variables around, you have a single copy and pass references.

This is a great article to get started: https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/